# Geocoding in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geocoding

I am using the geocoder package in Python to obtain the coordinates for a set of addresses (around 30k). I get the following error:

> Status code Unknown from
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json: ERROR -
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url:
>   /maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rancho+Palos+Verdes%2CCA%2CUS&bounds=&components=&region=&language=
>   (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed
>   out',)))

The number of times I receive the error reduces if I add the `time.sleep(x)` function but it significantly increases the time taken to execute the code. Is there a more efficient way to run the code?

Following is a snippet of the code:

```
for add in clean_address:
    g=geocoder.google(add)
    time.sleep(7)
    if(g.ok==True):
        lat.append(str(g.lat))
        lon.append(str(g.lng))
    if(g.ok==False):
        lat.append("")
        lon.append("")
```

Comment: Google's geocode API is only free up to a certain amount, you're probably exceeding that and getting rate-limited. If you want more you'll have to sign up and pay for your volume.

Comment: Is there a reason to use google api? you could use arcgis api that haven't use limitation:   g=geocoder.arcgis(add)

Comment: @Lupanoide - Thanks for the recommending me ArcGIS. Its more accurate and faster in getting the coordinates for my 31k records.

Comment: @Lupanoide - could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @MazahirBhagat sure, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google API has a [use limitation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering). However you could even use geocoder library that collects a lot of geocoding services. I suggest to you to use the [ArcGis api](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/ArcGIS.html#geocoding) that hasn't any limitation on usage and is very accurate.
The usage is very simple:

```
g=geocoder.arcgis(add)
lat.append(g.x)
lon.append(g.y)
```

Comment: arcgis still times out after several hundred records. I am a fair newbie at python and would like to know a method to catch this error and keep going

Answer (score 2):

This is an error originating in the Python `requests` library used by the `geocoder` package.  The error itself is likely a symptom of exceeding a [quota limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies#quota-limits) configured [on your project's enabled API](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/quotas).  There are short term quotas (per 100 seconds) and long-term quotas (per day) that you might be running into.

An improvement to automatically retry *with exponential backoff* may help if the error is due to short-term quota being exceeded.  To do this, explicitly create a [Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#request-sessions) with a custom [Retry](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html), and use that session with the `geocoder` library:

```py
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

...

# Retry for up to 65 seconds
ssn = requests.Session()
adp = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(total=16, backoff_factor=0.001))
ssn.mount('https://', adp)
ssn.mount('http://', adp)

...

geocoder.google(..., session=ssn)
```

Comment: Great answer but a follow up: What is the way to add retry functionality in R? I have R code which is running into the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Your addresses are **30K** and the limit is **2,5K** per day.

As Google quotes in the relevant [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key):

> To use the Google Maps Geocoding API, you must register your app
>   project on the Google API Console and get a Google API key which you
>   can add to your app or website.

After doing so, [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) are the limits:

> Users of the standard API:
>
> - 2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
> - 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

Comment: Is there a downvoting police in S.O.? I need to sue somebody.

Comment: no police. but i'll balance it out for you. I believe this answers the OP's question

Comment: The downvoters are the police (part of it anyway). Don't worry, the average statistics will work out in your favor. +1